# Can we add keychain access group entitlements in CommandLine application for Mac OSX?

Tags: objective-c, macos, command-line-tool

I have build a Command line tool app in Mac OSX to fetch tokens using Microsoft MSAL Objective-C framework. There is a need to provide the keychain-access-group entitlements for this app to cache the tokens in keychain.
I am not finding a way to provide entitlements to this command line application whereas in Cocoa app there is an option in Xcode to provide this entitlements.
I tried creating the entitlements file and provided the path under "Build Settings -> Signing -> Code Signing Entitlements" but this is not working.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. Entitlements file is placed into application' bundle, but if command-line tool is created, it will be compiled into single executable Mac OS X file, and bundle will not be created.

As an alternative approach You can try to embed this entitlement.file into binary itself, with some kind of encoding and representing as a data in the app, then unpack it to temporary directory on application' start and try to access it from that directory. But path to this file also should be hardcoded/calculated in the application, sue to no Info.plist with configuration is provided to command-line tool as well.